# Getting good result with sox pitch command

Tags: sampling

I am trying to transpose a sample across several octaves so I have a sample library of, in this case, someone singing "doo".

I recorded a sample in the middle of the range, and bulk transposed this to all the other relevant pitches using the sox pitch command.

However, the results are not very good. In the high register, for instance, listen to the front of the sound: https://adaptiveeartraining.com/magmaGold/js/samples/voice_doo/A5.wav. I can confirm the sample rate is the same as the original file.

(original audio for comparison: https://adaptiveeartraining.com/magmaGold/js/samples/voice_doo/D4.wav)

Using [AudioFinder](https://icedaudio.com/site/), I got much better results; all the "doos" sound great. However, I was not able to find how I can save each transposed sample to a new file and that's what I need to end up with.

Could someone advise a (free/cheap) workflow for ending up with my sample transposed do the different pitches that sounds decent? As AudioFinder shows, it seems possible without recording multiple samples. So perhaps adding some other commands to sox can help here?

Comment: It sounds like you're shifting pitch while retaining length - literally pitch-shifting rather than simply speeding up the sample.  To my knowledge, there are several formulae for achieving a pitch shift, all with different tonal qualities on the output. Do you know which formula Sox is using versus which formula AudioFinder is using? I don't know much about this subject but narrowing that difference down may help you figure out how to achieve the sound you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can try freely Reaper which use the Elastique library for pitch bending.

The software should only be used freely for a 60 days evaluation, but it is not that expensive.

Since it is a full DAW, you have to create a track, insert the Media item you want to transpose, search and modify the transposition in the item properties. Play it (and hear if it is correct), File/render will create the modified WAV or MP3.